# how to transform CLR to EXE

Tags: c#, .net, clr, executable

when we create an application in VC#, talking about .net 3.5 in particular, the are comipled to CLR, what i want is that they should be compiled to EXE executable code that doesn't require .NET Framework Environment for them to run. Is it possible

Comment: See this thread from May - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846978/how-to-convert-a-net-exe-to-native-win32-exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're asking how to statically link the parts of the framework your application needs. Please see this link from Jon Skeet for info on how to do that: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#framework.required

Answer (score 1):

There are 3rd party products that do this. I know of no free ones.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you get a third party product, I think it just packages the .NET runtime in there somehow. I don't know how else it would run.

Why don't you just create an installer that has the .NET framework as a requirement? It should check for it and install it if the user doesn't have it already.

Comment: people don't like ten types of frame works n runtimes on their PCs like me , i really have a problem with JRE

Comment: If you package the framework up with your application, you're going to end up with even more copies in scattered places. If you don't want have a framework installed then you might want to consider a different programming language. All those nice API calls have to live somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [MONO's](http://www.mono-project.com) ahead of time compiler